# how to set data expiration policy in DolphinDB

Tags: dolphindb, content-expiration

For the data in DolphinDB DFS databases, how can I set data expiration policy? For example, data before 6 months ago are automatically deleted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `setRetentionPolicy` function.

https://www.dolphindb.com/help/setRetentionPolicy.html